# IIS Admin Service won't start

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

I have a Windows 2003 SBS Server (SP2) that suddenly has a problem starting the IIS Admin Service.

This not only means that intranet sites are no longer available to the users but more importantly, Exchange has a service-dependency on the IIS Admin Service, meaning that Exchange won't run either.

I've found blogs online ([such as this one](http://jamesewelch.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/reinstalling-internet-information-server-iis/)) that say about uninstalling IIS, but it also says nearer the bottom that on restart, the problem happens again.

**

> (Edit:) There actually appears to be
>   an HTML email (with encoded attachment
>   text) *inside* the metabase.xml...
>   should that even be there???

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried lots of different means of trying to fix this, but had to resort to uninstalling the IIS section (through the Add/Remove Windows Features) and then had to reinstall it.

I found that if you do this, the IIS Admin Tool will restart, but I had to also reinstall the NNTP and SMTP sections to get Exchange to start up again.

Answer (score 0):

What does the Event log say?

That said, this command has saved me a couple of times for similiar issues with Exchange related services not starting.  This assumes the 32bit .NET 1.1 is messed up.

%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Here is the related KB from Microsoft

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435